# Need help regarding regex

Tags: regex

I need to identify this two sets of patters. One is

- **Case 1:**  2 letters then an optional space and then three numbers. For example: 'A012' or 'A 014'
- **Case 2:**  1 letter and then an optional space and then three consecutive numbers. For example: 'AB012' or 'AB 014'

I used the similar pattern, but it fails to catch some cases.

```
    const REGEX = /\b([a-zA-Z] *[a-zA-Z\d]{0,1} *[a-zA-Z\d] *(\.|,)? *\d *(\.|,)?[a-zA-Z\d])\b/g
```

Is there any suggestion?
It is not important whether the matched string is case 1 or case 2. Any match would be enough.

Comment: Please provide examples of cases that should match but do not

Comment: Are you extracting data or just trying to figure out if something is case 1 or case 2?

Comment: Are you sure you want "consecutive" numbers? Consecutive numbers follow eachother such as `123` or `678`. `014` is not consecutive, it's just 3 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one?

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,2} ?\d{3}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `\s` for this as OP mentioned specifically a space. A new line should presumably fail.

Comment: Thanks. You made my day.

Comment: No problem, overall the question is full of holes and even the case examples aren't listed under their respective bullet points.